# Pyplot - Unwanted gap on x-axis on moving plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, pyqt

I have a PyPlot Figure on a FigureCanvas with multiple plots which frequently clears and replots on a timer.

I want the x-axis to be the same length as the plots (See visual example below) as the plots traverse as subsets of the data, but instead this is happening:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Desired effect:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class WidgetResults(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        super(WidgetResults, self).__init__(parent)

        #-- Plotting variables
        self.data               # A collection of PlotPair objects (Defined below)
                                # x-axis: datetime, y-axis: percentage
        self.curScreen = 0      # Number of data points that have been traversed
        self.screenCount = 100  # Number of data points to be plotted at a given time

        #-- Canvas
        self.figure = plt.figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure) 
        self.canvas.setMinimumSize(350, 350) 
        self.canvas.setSizePolicy(QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.ax.grid()
        self.ax.set_yticks([0,25,50,75,100]) # y-axis will always be a percentage
        self.ax.set_xticks([])
        self.ax.set_ylabel("Percent")

        #-- Layout
        layoutMain = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layoutMain.addWidget(self.canvas)    
        self.setLayout(layoutMain)

        #-- Begin
        timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        timer.timeout.connect(self.updatePlot)
        timer.start(10)
        self.timer = timer
        self.plot()

    #-- Plots the initial graph
    def initialPlot(self):
        plots = self.data
        for i in range(len(plots)):
            plt = plots[i]
            dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(plt.getX())[0:int(self.screenCount)]
            vals = plt.getY()[0:int(self.screenCount)]
            self.ax.plot(dates, vals, colours[i])
        self.ax.set_yticks([0,25,50,75,100])
        self.ax.set_xticks([])
        self.canvas.draw()

    #-- Called on timer ticks  
    def updatePlot(self):
        self.curScreen+=1
        plots = self.data
        self.ax.clear() 
        for i in range(len(plots)):
            plt = plots[i]
            dates = matplotlib.dates.date2num(plt.getX())[self.curScreen:int(self.screenCount)+self.curScreen]          
            vals = plt.getY()[self.curScreen:int(self.screenCount)+self.curScreen]
            self.ax.plot(dates, vals, colours[i])
        self.ax.set_yticks([0,25,50,75,100])
        self.ax.set_xticks([])        
        self.ax.set_autoscale_on(False)
        self.canvas.draw()

#-- This class holds a representation of a graph plot.
#-- Contains two lists of points, x-axis and y-axis.
class PlotPair(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        self.xPlots = x
        self.yPlots = y

    def getPlots(self):

        plots = [self.xPlots, self.yPlots]
        return plots

    def getX(self):
        return self.xPlots

    def getY(self):
        return self.yPlots
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired result by adjusting the final lines in my updatePlot function.

It was important to redefine the yticks before redrawing, as these were reset in autoscale.

```
    self.ax.relim()
    self.ax.autoscale()
    self.ax.set_yticks([0,25,50,75,100])
    self.canvas.draw()
```